# Virtual Hosts not working properly using homebrew php dnsmasq mysql

Tags: virtualhost, homebrew, vhosts, dnsmasq

I spend a couple of days trying to figure out how to setup a local dev environment.
Using homebrew I installed php, mysql and dnsmasq.

Now I want any folder I add to my sites folder to automatically be available through `FOLDERNAME.dev`. Using this tutorial (http://akrabat.com/computing/automatic-apache-vhosts/) I was able to create the vhosts and navigate to the right folder but instead of the website, I get the folders view with all it's content

[image: folder view instead of actual site]

So I though apache wasn't running but I sudo'd `apachectl restart` and nothing changed.

Also when I tried using a laravel install with laravel.dev I get a 500 error

Does anyone have experiences with automatic vhosts and homebrew php/mysql?

I'm using
- Mac osx 10.8.3
- PHP 5.4.13
- MySQL 5.6.10
- DnsMasq 2.65

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question so you probably gave up or figured it out , but I followed this same setup and it took me nearly a week to get everything working perfectly so I thought I'd post my solution incase anyone else runs into this.

For your problem I believe it can be fixed modifying the DirectoryIndex line in httpd.conf to:
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php

There are a couple other posts about that blog you cited. Here's one that helped me figure it out.

http://blog.evan.pro/how-to-set-up-dynamic-virtual-hosts-for-web-development